# Elixir: ExAws: DynamoDB: query-filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, elixir

I'm using the library https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_dynamo, and I'm having issues getting a working example of `query-filter` to work with `query`. I was hoping someone here has an example they could share.

Here's what I've tried, but it returns an error:

```
[
  key_condition_expression: "highlight_request_id = :highlight_request_id",
  expression_attribute_values: [
    highlight_request_id: "c692e65e-618f-45a3-ac12-d8103e6444c8"
  ],
  query_filter: %{
    range_id: %{
      attribute_value_list: ["9990-ORGANIZATION-Pampers"],
      comparison_operator: "EQ"
    }
  }
]
```

and the error I get back:

```
{:error,
 {"ValidationException",
  "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'queryFilter.range_id.member.comparisonOperator' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"}}
```

I'm not sure what is considered to be `null`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your query is written like so (adapted from the ex_aws_dynamo tests):

```
ExAws.Dynamo.query("person", [
  index_name: "email",
  key_condition_expression: "#email = :email",
  expression_attribute_names: %{"#email" => "email"},
  expression_attribute_values: [email: "person@test.com", last_name: "Person"],
  filter_expression: "last_name = :last_name"
]) |> ExAws.request()
```

I was able to run this successfully against my local table, you'll have to fill in the appropriate values for your model.  In particular, you'll want to include the `index_name`, and use the `filter_expression`, rather than `query_filter`.

In your case, I believe you'd want something like

```
ExAws.Dynamo.query("person", [
  index_name: "highlight_request_id", # assuming that's the name of the index
  key_condition_expression: "#highlight_request_id = :highlight_request_id",
  expression_attribute_names: %{"#highlight_request_id" => "highlight_request_id"},
  expression_attribute_values: [highlight_request_id: "c692e65e-618f-45a3-ac12-d8103e6444c8", range_id: "9990-ORGANIZATION-Pampers"],
  filter_expression: "range_id = :range_id"
]) |> ExAws.request()
```

Let me know if this gets you any closer - again, worked for me, using the latest version of ex_aws_dynamo (2.2.2, at the moment).